# How to write a for loop for adjusted close prices on list of stock symbols?

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm an R beginner, but I'm trying to use quantmod to write a loop to pull adjusted stock prices for a series of dates (current, 6 months ago, 12 months ago, 18 months ago). I want to get a sense of the health of a company over time. However, I've run into error after error so am putting out what I have and hoping someone can help. I haven't been able to use getSymbols to fetch anything, so CompanyTickers is just from a .csv of symbols.

```
stocks <- (CompanyTickers$Symbol)

## Generate new environment stockEnv for results
stockEnv <- new.env()

##
## This pulls available stock data for the Symbols in the stock variable
## The try function keeps the code from quitting for defunct symbols
##
df <- try(getSymbols(stocks, src ='yahoo', env=stockEnv))


## Runs a loop on the data stored to stockEnv
## One Year ago
for (stock in ls(stockEnv)){
  try(monthlyReturn(xtsTicker, subset='2017-09-18')     
}
```

Comment: This might cover what you're asking: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/18758/how-do-i-loop-through-all-the-stocks-with-quantmod-and-ttr

Answer (score 0):

You have stored the result into an environment. When you use `ls` it fetches just the name(s) of the objects in that environment. You can use function `get` to fetch the object and work on it.

```
x <- new.env()
x$obj <- 1

for (i in ls(x)) {
  message("Accessing ls() result:")
  print(i)
  message("Properly fetch from environment")
  print(get(i, envir = x))
}

Accessing ls() result:
[1] "obj"
Properly fetch from environment
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will get you started. No need for a separate environment, just store everything in a list and use the apply functions to help you with looping over all the data. The monthlyReturn data needs something specified like I have below like "2017-09-18::" or "2017-09::". The monthly return calculation will take all the data from the month regardless if your starting date is in the middle of the month.

```
library(quantmod)

# stocklist with 1 bad stock
stocks <- c("MSFT", "MSFT2", "GIS")

# Get the data and name the list objects
stock_data <- lapply(stocks, function(x) try(getSymbols(x, src ='yahoo', auto.assign = FALSE)))
names(stock_data) <- stocks


# Show which stocks don't have any data
which(sapply(stock_data, is.character) == T)
MSFT2 
    2 

# remove stocks that don't return any data.
stock_data <- stock_data[!sapply(stock_data, is.character)]

# One Year ago
monthly_return_data <- lapply(stock_data, function(x) monthlyReturn(x, subset = "2017-09-18::"))
```

For data quality purposes you might want to check the source tiingo or Alphavantage (API keys needed). yahoo doesn't always have correct data.